# How to make css apply to jsp when using servlet to show jsp?

Tags: css, jsp, servlets

Using Eclipse - Dynamic Web Project.
I am basically showing page "Home.jsp" via this code in servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

But styles are not applied this way like they are when directly showing page via url (or just opening html file directly in file system). Is there some way how to apply them in doGet method (or somewhere else) ?

jsp:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <title>System</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <button type="button" class="homebutt">Concerts</button>
 <button type="button" class="loginbutt">Login</button>
 <button type="button" class="registrationbutt">Registration</button>
  <hr>
 <div>
  <select id="artistcombo">
     <option value="">Artist:</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="countrycombo">
     <option value="">Country:</option>
  </select>
   
  <select id="genrecombo">
     <option value="">Genre:</option>
  </select>
 </div>
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```css
button
{
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

button.homebutt
{
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: left;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 color: indigo;
}

button.loginbutt
{
 color: black;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
}

button.registrationbutt
{
 color: black;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
}
```

Project tree:
[image: Project tree]

Comment: Do not post image of your code! Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question in stackoverflow. Anyway, please add your jsp code and the tree of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files in the `WEB-INF` directory are not directly accessible to the end user. My suggestion is

1. move your css file to a directory outside `WEB-INF` but at the same level e.g. `resources`
2. change the import of the css file in the jsp as  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/style.css/>"`

Comment: Should i set ${pageContext.request.contextPath} somehow in servlet? Becouse moving css file and changing href like you suggested do not work...

Comment: @Wortig Edit the answer